# .equals method and Java String Pool

Tags: java

String a = "test";

why is
"test".equals(a)
true?

does the "test" in "test".equals(a) get the same reference as a from the string pool?
Thanks

Comment: The second question you ask is unrelated to the actual question (or the other way around). `equals` *should* make a logically meaningful comparison, and therefore it does make sense that `"test"` is equal to `a` because they have the same value, String pooling and string comparison are actually irrelevant here. You are mixing two completely unrelated topics.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be true?

Answer (score 1):

equals for String does not do a reference compare, does a value one.

For other classes you create, if you dont override equals and hashcode, it will do a reference compare, otherwise it will call your override.